# What is a good model for learning power equation against frequency for a chip

Tags: regression, modeling, model, linear

Here's my problem scenario:-
I have to come up with a power equation as a function of frequency. The plot fits well with a higher order polynomial (4th or 6th) :-

$$Power = \theta_0 + \theta_1 fr^1 + \ldots + \theta_6*fr^6$$

(This is from MS Excel's trend line for a scattered plot)
Frequency (x axis) ranges within fixed limits $f_1$ to $f_2$ and I have data from 100 different devices for this kind of frequency sweep.

With this limited data set what would be a good ML model to train and generalize the co-efficients that would work for any unseen device?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:-**

While I can't share the exact data-set here but let me share some info about the data- fr ranges from 4060($f1$) to 4165($f2$); I have an option to go granular i.e step size of +1 .. currently I am going +5

[image: Visualizing the data frame]

**Question:** Shall I treat each device as an example and each frequency as a feature? In that case the problem becomes multi-variate and I don't want that. I want the equation to remain exactly as stated above. The more desired option is to treat each frequency as an example, then how do I treat each of the 100 devices? definitely not as features.. How to model the problem space into a feature vector $X$ and ans vector $Y$ and param vector $\theta$?

Comment: Would you please post a link to some of the data? I can run it through my zunzun.com "function finder" and see if I can then suggest some candidate equations for you to consider.

Comment: @JamesPhillips: Thanks for your response, but I can't share the data frame.. my apologies.. I have given some more details about specific areas where I am seeking guidance .. Thanks!